# DNS Configuration for domains and subdomains to point to single IP

Tags: configuration, dns, subdomain, host

I have domain my-domain.com, I want to setup (DNS) sub domains to point to my '**PUBLIC IP**' where my website is hosted

Currently I have this, setup in DNS:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|        Domain          |    Type    |       Content        |
==============================================================    
|   www.my-domain.com    |     A      |    'PUBLIC IP'       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

and in my website host box, I setup one nginx server block point to my main website 'www.my-domain.com'

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-domain.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080
    }
 }
```

Now I want to run another website in the same box and i want it to be accessible using **blogs.my-domain.com**.  With this, I'm going to setup another nginx server block as :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blogs.my-domain.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081
    }
 }
```

How do i configure **blogs.my-domain.com** DNS Entry?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it as a CNAME record:

```
blogs.my-domain.com  CNAME  www.my-domain.com
```

Note that with some DNS software the above won't work because it is using relative domains, i.e. they don't terminate in a `.`.